# ActiveAdmin custom search filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a User class, which has an Address object with a phone field. Due to the nature of this project, we are saving phones in all sorts of formats (dashes, spaces, no spaces etc.). On my AA users.rb, I want to specify a filter that will standardize the phone data (get rid of dashes and spaces) of the saved data, and then perform the search against the admin input.

So the admin could search something like 1234567 and it would return 123-4567.

I'm hoping that something exists like...

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  ...
  filter :email
  filter :name
  filter :address_phone, custom: { Address.all.map{|x| x.phone.gsub("-","") } 
  ...
```

I appreciate it if anyone knows an easy way to accomplish this.

Comment: How many records we are talking here? I would cleanup my data on DB side (remove all invalid chars), then use a decent format function on the view to *represent* this data.

Comment: What is the version of the ActiveAdmin gem?

Comment: activeadmin 0.6.0, using meta_search